# Matlab: adding multiple 3D cartesian coordinate axes within a 3D plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**Getting right to the question:** How can I make my plot go from looking like this:
[image]

to something like this:

[image]

where a right-handed Cartesian coordinate system (with axis labels at the end of the arrows, e.g., in this example the x-axis label is = $x_1^G$)

**Some elaboration and prefacing:** First, I am new to matlab and "matrix math". I tried searching on this site for questions similar to what I have posed above but did not see anything (but I may have missed), so hopefully this is not a duplicate.

Here is the code I have used to develop my rotated ellipsoid (since I'm new to matlab I would appreciate any comments on my code):

```
%Insert the components of the 3x3 matrix (i.e. the scalar values of the 2nd-rank symmetric tensor)

Pmatrix = [115.9547 12.03765 4.68235; 12.03765 116.3702 -2.47985; 4.68235 -2.47985 134.5488];

[R,D]=eig(Pmatrix); %find the eigenvectors (R) and eigenvalues (D) of the 2nd-rank tensor

[x, y, z] =sphere; %generate coordinates of a sphere, using the sphere command

%Stretch the coordinates of the sphere to form the tensor's representation ellipsoid, do this by multiplying the x, y, z coordinates by the square-roots of the eigenvalues
x1 = x*sqrt(D(1,1));
y1 = y*sqrt(D(2,2));
z1 = z*sqrt(D(3,3));
figure;
hmesh = mesh(x1,y1,z1);
set(hmesh,'FaceColor',[0.5,0.5,0.5],'FaceAlpha',0.5) %set color to gray, make mostly transparent
axis equal; %Make tick mark increments on all axes equal
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');

theta1 = -asind(R(3,1)); %rotation around y-axis in degrees
psi1 = atan2d(R(3,2)/cos(theta1),R(3,3)/cos(theta1)); %rotation around x-axis in degrees 
phi1 = atan2d(R(2,1)/cos(theta1),R(1,1)/cos(theta1)); %rotation around z-axis in degress

direction = [1 0 0]; %rotate the surface plot psi1 degrees around its x-axis
rotate(hmesh,direction,psi1)
direction = [0 1 0]; %rotate the surface plot theta1 degrees around its y-axis
rotate(hmesh,direction,theta1)
direction = [0 0 1]; %rotate the surface plot phi1 degrees around its z-axis
rotate(hmesh,direction,phi1)

view([-36 18]);  %Change the camera viewpoint
```

**To add to my question**, I would like to add other (similar) items to my plot, so that the final product would look like this:

[image]

In the development of the image above, a set of axes collinear with the ellipsoid's eigenvectors are added (the red, green, blue arrows):

[image]

Then these axes are extended in the opposite direction, through the origin, where these portions of the axes are shown as a dashed lines:

[image]

Then, the angles between the global coordinate axes (black arrows) and the ellipsoid's axes (colored arrows) are notated as shown here:

[image]

To comment on this last addition, someone has built some matlab code with these features ([see youtube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zSY07bw6J0)).  In the video's description it says the matlab code [can be found here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24067-eular-angles-gui).  Being new to matlab, I don't see where the code is, e.g., I don't see where on this page (screenshot below) the code is to build that matlab plot seen in the youtube video.  If you can guide me on how to navigate that mathworks-fileexchage page that would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: My first approach would be to just draw the items separatedly, arrows, archs etc. If you think as them as just 3D lines, you can do it. Its a bit time consuming though, but eh, nice plots are nice plots. To get that tool, just download it. It will provide the entire code. There is also a "Fucntions" tab where you can see the code.

Comment: On the top-right of that web page is a star rating, underneath it says "9 downloads", and a little further down there is a blue button with white text that says "download". There you can fetch the code (I know it's hard to find!). Unpack it to any directory, change your current directory in MATLAB to that directory, then run the code as (hopefully) described in the package.